# VBA Macro to search a keyword from Excel file and return the file path with number of counts

Tags: vba, excel

VBA is interesting and I'm a Newbie.

I have an Excel file with a list of number that I have to find in a folder and I want to return the path as a link in my Excel file so I can open and verify the docs are right and then print

```
INVOICE DATE    INVOICE NO  DN          ORDER NO    COMPANY NAME
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
```

Say My folder path to search is `C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX`

For example

```
INVOICE DATE    INVOICE NO  DN          ORDER NO    COMPANY NAME
5/9/2017    XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX   XXXXX
```

I want to search the number of files with number under DN and Order No column and retrive count of the files founds in a column and most important retrieve the file path of files found in another column in same row and search the whole list till the end

`DN - 287484135` and `order No 580449925` - search by both the numbers

The naming convention of file in the folder are as below
`Delivery_0650_LF_XXXXX_Delivery_note.PDF` - This is for DN
`Order_9250_TA_055699732_File Name..TIF` - This is for Order No
`Order_9250_TA_052835641_Copy_of_customer_PO.TIF` - This is for Order No

Or at least please suggest to verify if the keywords are found ot organise the work effectively.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: If you just want the number of rows which has the value `x` in column `y` or column `z`, then I would suggest using `COUNTIFS()`. It should be quite simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something around these lines. This Code scans every File in the Folder in `Path` and compares the with the Ord No. `Name`. The Function then returns the Number of Files and the paths in the format `counter, path, path, ...`.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Path1 As String, Data() As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
lRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Path1 = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files\"
Col = 3
For i = 2 To lRow
    If sht.Cells(i, Col).Value <> "" Then
        sht.Cells(i, Col + 5).Value = Scan(Path1, sht.Cells(i, Col).Value)
    End If
    If i = lRow Then
        If Col = 4 Then
           Exit For
        End If
        Col = 4
        i = 0
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Function Scan(ByVal MyPath As String, Name As String) As String
Dim File As String, temp As String
Dim i As Integer: i = 0

File = Dir(MyPath & "*.*")

Do While File <> ""
    If File Like "*" & Name & "*" Then
       i = i + 1
       temp = temp & MyPath & File & ","
    End If
    File = Dir()
Loop
temp = i & "," & temp
Scan = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Dear UGP, when i run this code, after 30 secs , it says 'Not responding". I will attach excel sheet if possible

Comment: Hello UGP, agree, I edited the code and used it. It works Absolutely fine. The the values are coming in the cell.  The only problem I am having is , I am not able figure out why the excell starts not respong after the value have incorporated in excel

Comment: It show error debug at sht.Cells(i, Col + 5).Value = Scan(Path, sht.Cells(i, Col).Value). May be limit is uper or lower limit is not set. Ot it is not able to find out when to stop or end running the code

Comment: I did a few small changes, dont know if they change anything for you. i dont know where the error could comes from. i tried, but couldnt recreate the error you got.

Comment: Excellent, Supercool, this works perfectly find. Thanks you so much, Much Appreciated

Comment: it is possible to Hyperlink the path, so I can directly Click and the file opens. Please advise

Comment: Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel)

Comment: I tried a lot but could not create the file path as hyperlink where cell has more than 1 path. Please help , that will be really helpful

Comment: Excel allows only one hyperlink per cell, you could use a workaround like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/982162/how-to-add-2-hyperlinks-in-a-single-cell-in-excel-2010). Or just use multiple cells.